# How does CNTK use sequence ids during training?

Tags: cntk

Sequence ids are optional in CNTK text format. I am wondering how sequence ids are used during training. When a minibatch is created from a CNTKTextFormat with sequence ids, is a line in CNTKTextFormat considered as one sample or all lines with the same sequence id together is considered as one sample?

Answer (score 1):

If IDs are given, then all lines with the same sequence ID are forming together one training instance (in CNTK lingo: they are forming a sequence consisting of samples).

If IDs are missing, then each line is a new training instance (consisting of a sequence with a single sample).

Comment: thanks. follow up questions, does a training instance mean all samples in the same training instance must go in sequence and cannot be dividided or change order? is minibatch size defined by sample count or training instance count? for example if a sequence has 50 samples, and minibatch size is set as 32, how does this work?